# Android tests documentaton

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing

On the same android sdk documentation web page:
http://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#config-local-tests

We can read the following:

"In your Android Studio project,
you must store the source files for local unit tests under a specific source directory 
src/test/java"

Lines later:

"In your Android Studio project,
you must place the source code for your instrumentated tests under a specific directory
src/androidTest/java."

So, where are we supposed to put our test sources?

Answer (score 4):

Either or both. They are for different types of tests. The first quote is from [a section entitled "Configure Your Project for Local Unit Tests"](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#config-local-tests). The second quote is from [a section entitled "Configure Your Project for Instrumented Tests"](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html#config-instrumented-tests). Those are not the same thing.

In a nutshell:

- "Local unit tests" means "tests that run on the JVM of your development machine, mostly for testing POJOs, other non-Android-specific code, or Android code that you mock incessantly"
- "Instrumented tests" (referred to previously as "instrumentation tests") means "tests that run on Android, and therefore can test code that depends heavily on Android"

This is covered in [the Testing Concepts documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html).